# Highcharts xrange Refusing to follow HOVER or SCROLLBAR behavior

Tags: javascript, highcharts, xrange

i'm trying to massage an xrange graph into a timeline like graph and have made an overall awesome widget but i'm running into problems with the Fit and Finish. I'd like to be able to have a YAxis Scrollbar so that i can have many 'Agents' shown in the same graph as well as having the bar darken when hovered over. Unfortunately i can't get any of the attributes from the Highcharts API to actually do anything - i am having the same problem using the jsFiddle they supply you with. See code snipit regarding yAxis and hover state.
    `yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        minPadding: .11,
        scrollbar: { //todo not working - 
            enabled: true,
            showFull: true
        },
        categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        reversed: true
    },...
    states: {
            hover: {
            enabled: true,
            brightness: -0.9 //todo not working WTF
          }
        },`

(link: https://jsfiddle.net/uaqp5tj7/16/#&togetherjs=uufALv7hEj)

if you have any ideas please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not use both `highcharts.js` and `highstock.js` scripts, use only `highstock` and scrollbar will work.

To adjust scrollbar to your needs, you should set axis extremes, not the chart height:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    ...
},
```

To achieve point `hover` effect, you can use `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events:

```
series: [{
    point: {
        events: {
            mouseOver: function() {
                this.graphic.element.children[0].setAttribute(
                    'opacity', '0.5'
                );
            },
            mouseOut: function() {
                this.graphic.element.children[0].setAttribute(
                    'opacity', '1'
                );
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}]
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L9rx0vbg/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis

Comment: That was it - so i needed to import /modules/stock.js so i could run highcharts and highstock on the same page (widgets of both types) thank you !

Comment: You need to use only `highstock` - it allow you to create `stockChart` and basic `chart`, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/amu4qd7L/